# Should config.h be made public? Conflict with Python

Tags: autotools

I am working on a C library that has SWIG bindings to Python.  In my autotools configuration, I check for the gettimeofday function.  I have discovered that I can't compile the Python portion of my project because it conflicts with a file `pyconfig.h`, which also defines HAVE_GETTIMEOFDAY.

This seems like a very general problem, I was surprised to see Python's `config.h` conflicting with my own.  In my project I keep `config.h` private---i.e., not installed with `make install`.  My impression is that this is correct.  I found at least [one blog post](http://inaugust.com/post/68) where this opinion is shared.

Is it a bug that Python conflicts with my `config.h`?

Edit: I solved it by adding

```
AC_DEFINE(Py_PYCONFIG_H,[],[Defined here to avoid conflicts with pyconfig.h])
```

to my `configure.ac`.  Question still stands, should `config.h` be public in your project, or kept private, only available to implementation files during build?

Comment: Good question. I work on a project that makes this public too, just like Python--and I think you're right, it seems like a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should not be made public to avoid problems like the one you're having. See the [Gentoo autotools best-practices document](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/articles/autotools-practices.xml), specifically, the paragraph that starts with **The config.h header file should be considered to be an internal header file**.

In your case, I would do exactly the same thing that you did: add a #define that prevents processing that file.

Comment: Thanks, good to get some confirmation.  Maybe I'll file it as a Python bug.